# full table join in powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

In powerpivot, `Related(Othertable[field])` retrieves the associated column from a related table.

I would like to import ALL such columns, doing the equivalent of a join.

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: nicolas, can you please shares some sample data and explain a bit more what the desired result should look like?

Comment: Nicolas, the real question is why would you want to do this ? :-) If you have to include the extra columns then doing it on import is your best bet but you should probably be using DAX and relationships to achieve the same result in a more efficient way.

Comment: @PetrHavlík well Related brings one column. I want them all.

Comment: @Jacob I am binding some model to each column in the Data Model, and I am missing an operator to inverse a relationship. so I need to denormalize the table, while keeping the main parent table. of course I could duplicate the information upon import as you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**nicolas**,

the smartest thing to do from my perspective is to merge your queries into one so that you can keep your original tables.

I would suggest using new [PowerQuery *Merge* funcionality](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx), which is very easy and works reliably (and also supports loading data directly into your PowerPivot data model).

Or you can write you custom Query in PowerPivot - if you use MSSQL (or any other) database as your source, you can actually use JOIN directly in the [PowerPivot window with *Table Import Wizard*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399137(v=sql.105).aspx) that makes things a bit easier.

**So the answer is: keep your original data tables intact, and create a new one that will be merging them together just for the purpose of your desired report.**

Hope this helps.

[image]